# How to assign a variable name to matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to assign a particular variable name to the generated matplotlib picture. However, I am not able to do so. Here is the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
step = 0.04
maxval = 1.0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

matplotlib.pyplot.jet()
r = np.linspace(0,1.25,50)
p = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
R,P = np.meshgrid(r,p)
X,Y = R*np.cos(P),R*np.sin(P)

Z = ((R**2 - 1)**2)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$\phi_\mathrm{real}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$\phi_\mathrm{im}$')
ax.set_zlabel(r'$V(\phi)$')

kurs = 252

plt.savefig(kurs, format='png')
```

As you can see, I am trying to assign a variable named 'kurs' as the name of the picture. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign a variable name to a figure"? Do you want to use the contents of a variable as the filename? Do you want some kind of object which represents the "png" output (i.e. a numpy array)? Normally, one would just give the savefig a filename and that is the end of the story.

Comment: @pelson - sir, I was willing to save a file with a randomly selected unique name, every time the script is called. Exactly, I was willing to use the content of the variable as the filename.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks like @joaquin's answer is ideal then. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of a file must be a string, not a number.
Try:

```
kurs = '252'
```

Still it would be more convenient to use something line '252.png'.
If you are assigning the names from some kind of number generator you could do:

```
for i in range(10):
    ...................
    ...................
    kurs = "%i.png" % i
    plt.savefig(kurs, format='png')
```

Comment: Thank you joaquin. You solved my problem! I am retrieving a random integer to serve as an identifier for the saved image. Now, I will convert it into string - thanks.